# Multiple rows in same column - table in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I would like my front page Wiki-page to consist of three columns - each representing one department.
The separate departments will update their own column so I really need the columns to behave a certain way.

```
************************************************
* Department 1  * Department 2  * Department 3 *
************************************************
* Dept 1 Info 1 * Dept 2 Info 1 * Dept 3 Info 1*
************************************************
* Dept 1 Info 2 * Dept 2 Info 2 * Dept 3 Info 1*
************************************************
* Dept 1 Info 3 *               * Dept 3 Info 1*
*****************               ****************
* Dept 1 Info 4 *               
************************************************
```

I've tried to accomplish this with:

```
{|border=1
!Department 1
!Department 2
!Department 3
|-
|Dept 1 info 1
|Dept 1 info 2
|Dept 1 info 3
|Dept 1 info 4
|-
|Dept 2 info 1
|Dept 2 info 2
|-
|Dept 3 info 1
|Dept 3 info 2
|Dept 3 info 3
|}
```

But it doesn't work the way I need it to work.. I would like my end users to add content to the dept 3 info coloumn without affecting dept 1 and 2.

But how?

Comment: Why do you want the rows, do you really need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to have rows from different departments aligned? If not, you could create a separate table for each department and put them into one big table. Something like:

```
{|
!Department 1
!Department 2
!Department 3
|-
|
{|
|Dept 1 info 1
|-
|Dept 1 info 2
|-
|Dept 1 info 3
|-
|Dept 1 info 4
|}
|
{|
|Dept 2 info 1
|-
|Dept 2 info 2
|}
|
{|
|Dept 3 info 1
|-
|Dept 3 info 2
|-
|Dept 3 info 3
|}
|}
```

With Wikipedia's `wikitable` style, that looks like (you might want to make your own style for it):

[image: The table]

Comment: Thank you very much! I inserted a valign=top as well to make to vertically aligned to top.